# Fittign non-linear data in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I have a some noisy data I am trying to fit a function to.  Below is a pic of what the data shape looks like. Can someone recommenced functions/code I should try to fit the data? Pls be kind im a newbie!

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't recommend starting with "functions / code"; I'd recommend starting with *theory*. What is the source of the data? Is there some theoretical reason that it should have one shape or another? Perhaps there's a way that you can transform it so that it becomes linear? And so on. (And sure, maybe you have a genuine absence of any theoretical foundation here -- but that should be your first avenue to explore, not your second or third.) My **guess** is that you're headed for a transformation of your data and then a linear model -- but I don't know since I don't know the context of the data.

Comment: Its distribution has a long tail, doesn't it? Have you tried to check the histogram?

Comment: I 'm guessing that if you plot(log(x), y) you'll get something more amenable to regression.